# Курс CS50 язык С

Tags: c, cs50

Выдаёт ошибку "control may reach end of non-void function". Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так.

```
int find_length(long n)
 {
    int len;
    for (len = 0; n!=0; n/=10, len++)
    return len;
 }
```

Comment: Точку с запятой забыли после `for(...)`

Comment: Даже не обратила внимание... Спасибо ахах

Comment: Дайте индексируемое название вопросу

Comment: @yoitsib а это всё из-за желания впихнуть невпихуемое. Все эти нагромождения только ухудшают код.

Answer (score 2):

У вас получается

```
for (len = 0; n!=0; n/=10, len++) return len;
```

Если `n` не равно 0, то выполняется возврат `len`, равного 0.

А если `n` равно 0, то цикл не выполняется, и получается, что функция ничего не возвращает, хотя должна.

Вы, похоже, просто забыли точку с запятой:

```
for (len = 0; n!=0; n/=10, len++);
return len;
```

Comment: Да, я уже заметила) Спасибо!

Comment: @yoitsib если решение отвечает на вопрос, поставьте галку слева от него